# What is the use of JdbcApprovalStore(ApprovalStore) in spring-security-oauth?

Tags: java, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I am using `JWTTOkenStore` in spring-security-oauth.

The issue I am facing is I want to add support of revoking JWT token.
I know there are other options to handle this but I am looking for this option.
I found that we can use `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.JdbcApprovalStore` for the same. Is my understanding correct? I really searched on internet for some example, but I did not find any.

```
    /**
     * ApprovalStore to be used to validate and restrict refresh tokens.
     * 
     * @param approvalStore the approvalStore to set
     */
    public void setApprovalStore(ApprovalStore approvalStore) {
        this.approvalStore = approvalStore;
    }
```

Can someone please explain me briefly what is the use `JdbcApprovalStore` with `JWTTokenStore`?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Hi @027 did you solve this yet? Stuck on it

Answer (score 3):

Approval stores are used to manage the decisions (approvals) made by the users (accept or deny an app). These decisions can be stored on a **db ([jdbc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/approval/JdbcApprovalStore.html))**, **[in memory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/approval/InMemoryApprovalStore.html)** **or** a third which is the **[TokenApprovalStore](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/approval/TokenApprovalStore.html)**. In this one, the approvals are stored on the TokenStore itself. In your case, you would need this last one.

The use of JDBC with JWT is that, whenever a token is validated by the app, it would validate if the approval which appears inside of it is the same that the one stored on a certain place (jdbc, memory or tokenStore).

I hope this helps you, I'm just starting with OAUTH